# Handsontable Get source data given table row data (not original row in source)

Tags: handsontable

I'm using handsontable (https://handsontable.com/) and I create the sourceData with an additional parameter like it was another column (never used to render the table).

Then, afterChange, I need to get that parameter back.

The afterChange is working as expected, giving me the row number and the col header.

What I need is to be able to get the sourceData belonging to the object (not the cell) of the row.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what do you need, can you show code maybe i can help you ;)

Comment: I solved it with an external lookup table. I needed to pass an attribute to a row and read it later.